# Drinks Shirley - Slang for overhead dispenser?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, etymology

In a TV series, a man from London (living in Canada) asked for the house bar using the word "Drinks Shirley".

What does it mean exactly? Is it this kind of dispenser?

[image: Drinks dispenser]

Comment: Or maybe you heard "surely"? ("[And stop calling me Shirley!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wlpxl0WzaXg)")

Comment: Turns out it's neither "surely" (nice one Brian!) nor "Shirley", but "Trolley" with a British accent.

Comment: *Shirley you jest!*

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is entirely predicated on a mishearing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's probably a somewhat roundabout derivation from [***trolley dolly***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/trolley+dolly) (also, more rarely, ***cart tart***), meaning the female flight attendant who primarily serves you *drinks*.

It's a bit fanciful to suppose ***Shirley*** owes anything to the fact OED lists this as an old word for the [*South American tanager*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/tanager) (another bird, just not the same as [*dolly bird*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/dolly-bird)). I wouldn't rule out possible influence from a [*Shirley Temple cocktail*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shirley_Temple_%28beverage%29) (though that's actually non-alcoholic).

But (particularly noting @Brians [*Stop calling me Shirley!*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wlpxl0WzaXg) link), I think we can reasonably say ***Shirley*** is an almost randomly-chosen [*slightly disparaging woman's name*](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=-6h_EFb--YcC&pg=PA86&dq=%22is%20a%20shirley%22%20-%22shirley%20temple%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=nVOwU7T0LoLXOYjigcgO&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22is%20a%20shirley%22%20-%22shirley%20temple%22&f=false) (similar to the way Brits use [***Sharon*** and **Tracey**](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-1087586/KEITH-WATERHOUSE-Sharon-Tracy-face-future.html)). You could also compare the usage to [***dumb waiter***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dumbwaiter).

---

I should also say the usage has *no meaningful currency*. I've just checked [*all 55 instances*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22tidy%20up%20these%20toys%20I%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22drinks%20shirley%22&start=50&tbm=bks) of the two-word collocation in Google Books, and not a single one reflects OP's cited usage.

Comment: Thanks FumbleFingers for the detailed answer, you actually got the right word it in - although I misunderstood the word: It's [**"drinks trolley"**](http://www.rewardmanufacturing.com/media/catalog/product/cache/2/image/320x320/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/N/o/No-65.jpg) (found a subtitle online).

Comment: @CoDEmanX: Wot? You mean you *misheard* "Shirley" for "trolley"? I was actually going to mention that a sufficiently drunk speaker might feasibly slur his words enough to make *trolley* sound like *surely*, but I thought I'd written enough by that point. Ah well - at least *you* got your answer, even though it's unlikely to be relevant to anyone else in future.

Comment: Yes, I did :( But it's rather due to English not being my native language than the speaker's condition.

Comment: @CoDEmanX: You should probably be asking questions on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) rather than here. I won't closevote because I've answered, but this will very likely get closed as "entirely predicated on a mishearing". That probably *wouldn't* happen on ELL, where someone might even be able to point out that speakers of certain languages are prone to mix up the sounds involved (even when the *speaker* isn't drunk! :)